# Pulling specific dynamic text

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to pull the number amounts (32, 81154, 250000) out of the block of HTML below and stick them in a variable so I can build a progress meter with them.  Wondering what would be the most efficient way to do this with jquery as there may be up to 6 of these one one page.

So the numbers could be anything but the layout of the html will not change.  So I want to select the numbers between "Progress: " and " "< br/ >", "Raised: $" and "$nbsp;", "Goal: $" and "< /td >"

```
<div id="progress">
<table summary="layout table">
<tr>
<td>
Progress: 
32% 
<br />


Raised: $
81154 
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
Goal: $
250000 

</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use regular expression for that.

like : `/(\d+)/g`

take a look at [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5WJ9v/113/) but make sure your table data doesn't change.

Comment: So to get the different amounts into variables would I just use split? Or is there a better way?

Comment: @MarkK yes use `split`

Comment: var amounts = ($("#progress").text().match(regex))+" ";
     var daVars = amounts.split(",");

Answer (score 0):

Use Regexp `/\d+/g`

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/5WJ9v/114/)

```
$('#progress table').text().match(/\d+/g);
```

Reference

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/